# Unable to run REST APIs from Oracle RDS instance using APEX_WEB_SERVICE

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, oracle-apex, amazon-rds, restful-url

We have Oracle 12c RDS instance and REST SERVICES APEX installed on it. We were trying to make an API request from DB procedure using **APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request** but we are not able to make it.

```
**APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request (
p_url => API Url,
p_http_method => 'POST',
p_body => input_clob)**

We are getting below error when tried to do.

*ORA-29273: HTTP request failed
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist*

W have security groups created for Outbound on RDS and Inbound on API containers with the required port. But still we face the same issue

Can some one please let me know if I am missing anything ?

Thanks in Advance !!
```

Comment: when you paste the API URL in the browser, what happens?

Comment: We are able to run the API successfully from Postman.

Comment: Can you ping the url address directly from the database server?

Answer (score 0):

We were able to run the APIs when we use IP address in API URL.. seems like some DNS entry issues.. Thank you all !!